# How to test a Spark SQL Query without Scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure out how to test Spark SQL queries against a Cassandra database -- kind of like you would in SQL Server Management Studio. Currently I have to open the Spark Console and type Scala commands which is really tedious and error prone.

Something like:

```
scala > var query = csc.sql("select * from users");
scala > query.collect().foreach(println)
```

Especially with longer queries this can be a real pain.

This seems like a terribly inefficient way to test if your query is correct and what data you will get back. The other issue is when your query is wrong you get back a mile long error message and you have to scroll up the console to find it. How do I test my spark queries without using the console or writing my own application?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `bin/spark-sql` to avoid construct Scala program and just write SQL.

In order to use `bin/spark-sql` you may need to rebuild your spark with `-Phive` and `-Phive-thriftserver`.

More informations on [Building Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html). Note: do not build against `Scala2.11`, thrift server dependencies seem not ready for the moment.

Comment: Maybe because I am using DataStax Enterprise, but there is not spark-sql on my system that I can see. Spark comes pre-installed but maybe it's not the full version??

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites, I'm afraid so, https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/bin, you could see `spark-sql` there, in apache spark

Comment: As of DSE 4.7 which dropped today, thirftserver is supported via `dse start-spark-sql-thriftserver`

Answer (score 2):

You can write SQL in a file, read it in a variable in your testing script and set ssc.sql(file.read()) [Python way]

But it seems you are looking for something else. A test approach may be?

Comment: Yeah, some kind of web or desktop UI where I can paste queries and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example:

[donghua@vmxdb01 ~]$ **$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-sql --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-M2-s_2.11 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1**

spark-sql> **select * from kv where value > 2;**

Error in query: Table or view not found: kv; line 1 pos 14

spark-sql> **create TEMPORARY TABLE kv USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra OPTIONS (table "kv",keyspace "mykeyspace", cluster "Test Cluster",pushdown "true");**

16/10/12 08:28:09 WARN SparkStrategies$DDLStrategy: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE kv USING... is deprecated, please use CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW viewName USING... instead
Time taken: 4.008 seconds

spark-sql> **select * from kv;**
key1    1
key4    4
key3    3
key2    2
Time taken: 2.253 seconds, Fetched 4 row(s)

spark-sql> select substring(key,1,3) from kv;
key
key
key
key
Time taken: 1.328 seconds, Fetched 4 row(s)

spark-sql> **select substring(key,1,3),count(*) from kv group by substring(key,1,3);**
key     4
Time taken: 3.518 seconds, Fetched 1 row(s)
spark-sql>