# Running complex SQL queries on Cassandra tables using Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

hereI have setup Cassandra and Spark with cassandra- spark connector. I am able to create RDDs using Scala.  But I would like to run complex SQL queries (Aggregation/Analytical functions/Window functions) using Spark SQL on Cassandra tables , could you help how should I proceed ?[getting error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2mRe.png)

following is the query used :
sqlContext.sql(
   """CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE words
     |USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
     |OPTIONS (
     |  table "words",
     |  keyspace "test",
     |  cluster "Test Cluster",
     |  pushdown "true"
     |)""".stripMargin)

below is the error :[enter image description here][2]

new error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2mRe.png)

Comment: Spark SQL is rich compared to CQL , so would like to implement analytics using this.

Comment: I am able to get the rdds created for Cassandra tables using scala. (I am using Ubuntu terminal), but couldn't get the exact procedure to query Cassandra tables using spark-sql. could you help

Comment: following command used to start spark -sql based on one of the questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293070/how-to-test-a-spark-sql-query-without-scala but getting error .

$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-sql --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-s_2.11 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1

Comment: hi included the error screenshot and the query used , please check

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed from your post is that , `sqlContext.sql(...)` used in your query but your screenshot shows `sc.sql(...)`.

I take screenshot content as your actual issue. In Spark shell, Once you've loaded the shell, both the [SparkContext](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sparkcontext.html) (sc) and the [SQLContext](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spark_sql/spark_sql_dataframes.htm) (sqlContext) are already loaded and ready to go.  `sql(...)` does't exit in SparkContext  so you should try with `sqlContext.sql(...)`.

Comment: thanks balaji, this time I am getting error :
error not found value sqlContext

added screenshot to the descirption

Comment: previous error : sql was not a member of org.apache...**.. sparkcontext


now : not found value sqlContext

Comment: just give sc and press enter . and see what happens . and do the same for  sqlContext.

Comment: sc : not found value sc 
same for sqlContext as well

Comment: Yes , in Scala now

Comment: okay.  did you notice any error while opening the shell ? if thats the case, then its not problem with your code but problem with shell (environment).

Comment: Balaji , the create table sytax is deprecated, I used create  view instead and it worked. will share more details ..

Answer (score 0):

Most probably in your `spark-shell` context started as `Spark Session` and value for that is `spark`. Try your commands with `spark` instead of `sqlContext`.